# SSRS 2012 SP3 report throws error "Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long"

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

We were having this issue with one of our reports where the parameter length was huge and therefore the drill functionality was breaking the report with error  "Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long".

After searching around the fix it was available for SP1 Cumulative Update (CU) 8. Unfortunately the SP1 is retired and therefore I installed the latest service pack (SP3) with all the latest CU3 but the issue is still there.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to correct this issue. I have been searching around but can't seem to find the answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a browser issue rather than a reporting service issue - see [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) , in which case you are going to have to consider relocating your files.

Comment: Reports were working fine when they were running on SSRS 2005.